# Can Picard's theorem be used to show boundedness? (Differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP $$y'(t)=2ty(t)(y(t)-1)\\ y(0) = 1/2$$
I have been asked to show that $y$ is bounded by $$0 < y(t) <1$$ with strict inequality without solving the differential equation, under the assumption that a solution exists for all reals $t$. We have been given the hint to "Apply the Picard-Lindelof theorem". I am confused how this existence-uniqueness theorem can be employed to show boundedness.

My attempt has been to dissect the proof of the theorem and construct a uniformly convergent sequence of functions $y_n(t)$on the real line (As in the proof of the theorem), and then show that for each value of $t$, we have that $y_n(t)$ converges to a real number in $[0,1]$. While I have had some success in this method, the computations become extremely labor-intensive and I believe this approach is beyond the scope of the course.

How might one proceed with this problem?

Comment: IMHO, the hint is trying to tell you to use *uniqueness* of solutions, given by the theorem of Picard. $y=0$ and $y=1$ both are solutions to the differential equation, thus the given solution cannot intersect them.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation $$y'(t)=2ty(t)(y(t)-1)$$ has two equilibrium points namely $y(t)=0 $ , and $ y(t)=1$

Note that solution curves do not intersect each other  due to the uniqueness of solution 
  passing through a given point.

Thus a solution starting at $y(0)=1/2$ is bounded by these two equilibrium points due to the uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this directly, using the uniqueness claim of Picard-Lindelöf for $y(t)\ne 0$ as $y=0$ is a solution,
$$\begin{align}
y'+2ty&=2ty^2\\ (e^{t^2}y)'&=2te^{-t^2}(e^{t^2}y)^2\\ (e^{t^2}y)^{-1}-2&=e^{-t^2}-1\\~\\
y(t)&=\frac1{1+e^{t^2}}
\end{align}$$
This indeed has the claimed boundedness properties.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{y'}{y(y-1)}=2t\Rightarrow \ln\left(\frac{1-y}{y}\right)=t^2+C_0\Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{1+e^{t^2+C_0}}\Rightarrow 0\lt y\lt 1\ \ \text{because of the initial conditions.}
$$

Comment: You would need to mention that this works because the signs of the terms in the logarithm are positive at the initial point and thus everywhere.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation. This is a consequence of the initial conditions.